# Trouble adding Spring hateoas to Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-hateoas

First post here so sorry if format is off.

Currently I am trying to follow this Spring Java tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/
I am just to the part of adding the hateoas dependency to the pom.xml, however when I try that I get this error:
[Dependency \prg.springframework.boot:spring-bot-started-hateos:' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGbQT.png)

I tried Googling it but much came up. I tried adding a version number as another post suggested but that gave the same error. Im still new to Spring and RestAPIs so I am really not sure what else to do, and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

EDIT: My IDE is Intellij. As well I had restarted the IDE and the error appears to have went away, however when I add the next block of code from the tutorial(follows adding the depnedncy by a paragraph):

```html
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
EntityModel<Employee> one(@PathVariable Long id) {

  Employee employee = repository.findById(id) //
      .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));

  return EntityModel.of(employee, //
      linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(id)).withSelfRel(),
      linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withRel("employees"));
}
```

I get errors on "EntityMode", "linkTo", and "methodOn"

Comment: It looks like you are using IntelliJ, and did you check if the hateos dependency is actually present or not?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what you mean by if it is present or not? The only way I know to see if its there is if its in the dependincies or not, I wouldnt know how else to check it, is there another way you're referring to?

Comment: Yes you can check inside external libraries in Project or you can check if the Heatos is actually working

Comment: Ahhh okay, I still have a lot to learn haha. I check in the project structure tab, and under libraries it is present: Maven: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.6.6